# Numerical simulation of sound propagation in air

Tags: waves, acoustics, simulations

How does one go about accurately modeling sound propagation in a room (with reflections, absorption, and diffusion characteristics) from the motion of a loud speaker? More specifically what are the governing equations that are needed? Obviously Naiver-Stokes but this is too general? Is there an easier way?

Comment: I doubt the field of acoustics is any "easier" than fluid dynamics.

Comment: This actually sounds way harder than simple Naiver-Stokes and fluid dynamics.  Naviar-Stokes deals with relatively low-velocity fluids whereas sound vibrations cause very high-velocity, high-frequency oscillations.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: NS equations for compressible media do contain all that is necessary for sound propagation, but they are definitely overkill.

Comment: I think the hardest part of this would be defining the domain to have multiple reflection points. Randy Leveque's *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems* covers acoustics in several different places.

Comment: If you're looking for practical methods there are many current methods! See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDL39J-i0yQ

Answer (score 4):

From your description I deduce that approximation of [geometrical acoustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_acoustics)  should be enough. For its applicability we need to ensure that

1. The sound could be described as *small perturbation* (so, no nonlinear effects).
2. Wavelengths of sound are much smaller than the dimensions of structures with which the sound interacts.

The main equation for geometrical acoustics would be the [eikonal equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation).

If for your applications the interference effects are essential, then linear acoustics approximation is needed. Main equation would be the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave_equation#In_three_dimensions) for pressure and/or velocity potential.

Comment: It's not my field, but eikonal seems a little bit oversimplified. I'm thinking of a 50Hz sound: we then have $\lambda = c/\nu = 340{\rm m\,s^{-1}} / 50{\rm Hz} \approx 7{\rm m}$: rather big compared with chairs, tables, peoples, bookshelves .... so I'd guess pressure / velocity potential wave equation would be the wisest.

Answer (score 0):

Upon assuming small oscillations and neglecting the viscosity of air, the linear three-dimensionsal wave equation with proper boundary conditions would do in the time domain or alternatively  Helmholtz equation in the frequency domain. The boundary value problem can be solved by a numerical method e.g. the finite element method.